# Implementing 'click()' function in Python 3 for automation with Selenium.

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Not be able 'click()' function work for me to open a dropdown menu.
Working on webcite: http://www.titleboxing.com/
Looking to automate upper left navtab 'Gloves', which if you point on, drops additional links. The first one is Boxing Traning/Sparring Gloves. Would like to automate 'click()' on that link. I tried to 'click()' by finding element by_XPath, by_CSS and by link-text. Selenium returns that the element is not clickable. 
If anybody know which approach should I use to automate 'click()' on that link so page moves to : http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves/training-sparring-boxing-gloves?

Comment: Show `Python` code you've already tried

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://www.titleboxing.com/")
print(driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".level-top>span").click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best way but this should work.Try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "http://www.titleboxing.com/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

#this is to close the popup
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.fancybox-item.fancybox-close').click()
except:
    pass


action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.level-top>span'))
action.click()
action.perform()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.level1.nav-1-1.first>a').click()
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot! ActionChains module was something new to me. Manually, you can actually click on Gloves tab witch will take you to an intermediate page: http://www.titleboxing.com/gloves. From that page you can click on Boxing/Trainig/Sparring Glover under Category section.  this would avoid exporting  ActionChains module. But for some reason I could not "click()" on 'Gloves' authomaticaly.  This ActionChains module is new to me and it is working. Learhed something new today. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hover mouse cursor over dropdown-menu to open it instead of clicking on it. So try following code that will allow you to perform mouse hover+selecting required drop-down menu option:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as chains    

drop_down_xpath = '//a[@class="level-top"]'
option_xpath = '//span[text()="Boxing Training / Sparring Gloves"]'
chain = chains(driver)
chain.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath(drop_down_xpath)).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_xpath(option_xpath)).click().perform()
```

Comment: TypeError: move_to_element() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to_element'

Comment: oh,  yeah, sorry. Updated. Try again

Comment: No errors this time. However, the page is not moving. still @ 
: http://www.titleboxing.com/

Comment: hm... weird. I checked it on `chromedriver` and it works

Comment: Are you sure that these lines were actually executed? maybe there are some logic operators that avoid execution

Comment: How do you keep lines separate in this comment box anyway? I